# Band 71 600 MHz

Tags: iphone

Starting with the iPhone XR, 600 MHz Band 71 communication is supported.  How can I test\ verify \ confirm that comms are using Band?  Is there a good recent NYC map that depicts band 71 deployment, that I can test at the end of this month?

Goals include:

1. Identifying positions to test band 71
2. Determining a test procedure

Comment: Which problem are you trying to solve here?

Comment: Thanks for the update, but what is so special about this band that you want to verify Apple‘s product description?

Comment: Does the band not have the greater ability to penetrate buildings and work over longer distances than its higher frequency predecessors?

Comment: I'm not a specialist on that I all. I'm just wondering why you want to verify something which is listed on https://www.apple.com/iphone-11/specs/

Comment: It is a relatively new feature: it takes time for tech to mature.  Understanding / testing the contours of new feature efficacy is interesting.  Paper does not refuse ink

Comment: Are you on T-Mobile? - If not, it definitely won't be used.

Comment: Yes, a TMO device and account will be tested